# XML Calculated binding path

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm looking for a way to bind a field to some aggregate value, based on the value in another attribute. I know there are several other ways to do this, but if I can make this work, it'll be considerably better than my alternatives.

This is what I have so far, using expression binding:

```
<Text text="{= ${path:'/ProjectStatus(${key})/status'} }"/>
```

Purpose: Bind to the ProjectStatus object that matches the key attribute of the current object, and get the status attribute from that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that won't work. You can't use expression binding for this purpose. Expression binding is quite powerful, but meant for formatting and a little bit of math, not for defining bindings.

It would also not be advisable to solve it this way. If you want to create a key for and entity, you should always use the `createKey` method of your ODataModel, to make sure that key follows the syntax corresponding with the property type. E.g.: `/ProjectStatus('ABC')` for a key of type `String`, or `/ProjectStatus(123)` for a key of type `Int`.

Best is to get your controller to perform a `bindElement` on the Text control. Something similar to this:

```
this.getView().byId("TextId").bindElement(
    oModel.createKey("/ProjectStatus", { Id: sKey })
);
```

After that you could just use `<Text text="{status}" />` to show the status of the project.